# Sending live data to a webpage via TCP

Tags: php, tcp, push

I want to stream live XML data (say stock prices) to a TCP socket on a web server. I then want users to be able to connect to a webpage and see the (updated) version of the latest data. What do I need to do?

I'm most comfortable with PHP so:

1. Write a script that runs on the server and listens to the socket.
2. When it receives new data (which will be every second) it parses it into the right format (say: name, price, change)
3. ?????
4. Have a webpage that has a table of the latest data
5. Use pusher.js (or something) to listen for changes to the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP Is not good solution for that. Take a look at [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) or [vert.x](http://vertx.io/). With Websockets you can transmit data. Its more effizient then PHP-Sockets.

Comment: Yeah; I guess I wanted to stick with PHP, but node.js and socket.io makes most sense.

Comment: Vert.x is getting [PHP support](https://github.com/jordanhalterman/vertx-php) now too. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use Server Sent Events, Websockets, Comet Iframes, long polling....

There are many many ways to do what you want, it all depends on **how** you want to do it.